# Pass variable from one function to another with Code Snippets wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables, shortcode, code-snippets

I have 2 functions on my WordPress site, In my first function I receive a value for a variable I created, how do I pass this variable to my other function. I have made use of Global when I know it is advised against using them but my variable in my second function remains null.

**My first function receives a response back from an API. I now want this response available in my second function.**

**function 1:**

```
global $body;
$body = "response from my API";
```

**My second function allows the variable to be shown on my site in the form of a short code, but it receives nothing.**
**function 2:**

```
add_action('wpcf7submit','torque_hello_world_shortcode');           
function torque_hello_world_shortcode() {
   global $body;
   echo $body;
   return $body;
}
add_shortcode( 'helloworld', 'torque_hello_world_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Are both these functions run in one execution of a script or are you trying to pass data between php executions?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, so they are both running in the same execution but at different times, they are running in the contact form 7 plugin on WordPress, my first function runs on```add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail)``` so it receives the value before the end of the submission and my second function runs on ```add_action('wpcf7submit')``` so that it runs as the form is submitted.

Comment: I dont think they are the Same Execution! Try putting that data into the session

Comment: Hey RiggsFolly, I am afraid I don't follow what do you mean by putting the data into the session, do you mean to show my entire code? more information is it's all in one script that then needs to run at different times using the add_action method